Neo4J APOC Trigger Update Query
I'am trying to create trigger when my node value(name) will be update my trigger should be execute
But trigger doesn't execute
Please help me I stuck here from last 2 days.
Code is compiled properly, Only trigger is not executing
My Update-node.js function
//Initialize Connection
const driver = neo4j.driver('bolt://localhost:7687', neo4j.auth.basic('neo4j', '********'));
const session = driver.session();
const triggerCypher = use system CALL apoc.trigger.install('neo4j', 'update-node', 'UNWIND apoc.trigger.propertiesByKey({assignedNodeProperties}, "name") AS prop WITH prop.node AS node, prop.key AS key, prop.old AS oldValue, prop.new AS newValue create (p:Log{logDetails:"Log Created"}) return p ', {phase:'afterAsync'});
//Run Query
await session.run(triggerCypher);
I update node value from neo4j desktop app
match (p:Person) set p.name="john" return p

Just replace phase from {phase:'afterAsync'} to {phase:'before' or 'after' it will work
